# Getting Error: TensorList shape mismatch: Shapes -1 and 3 must match using tensorflowjs

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have trained a Mobilenet Tensorflow model using the Object Detection API on Google Colab. After I finished training, I  save the Saved Model and run the model in Python. The model works fine and it is detecting the objects as expected.

To convert the checkpoint to a tensorflow saved model:

```sh
python /content/models/research/object_detection/exporter_main_v2.py \
    --trained_checkpoint_dir {model_dir} \
    --output_directory {output_directory} \
    --pipeline_config_path {pipeline_file}
```

I load and predict the Model in Python using :

```py
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("path....")


def run_inference_image(model, image):
    image = np.asarray(image)
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image)
    input_tensor = input_tensor[tf.newaxis, ...]
    output_dict = model(input_tensor)
    num_detections = int(output_dict.pop('num_detections'))
    output_dict = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                   for key, value in output_dict.items()}
    output_dict['num_detections'] = num_detectionss.
    output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict['detection_classes'].astype(
        np.int64)
    return output_dict
```

To convert the model to tensorflowjs I am running the following command:

```sh
tensorflowjs_converter --control_flow_v2=True --input_format=tf_saved_model --metadata= --saved_model_tags=serve --signature_name=serving_default --strip_debug_ops=True --weight_shard_size_bytes=4194304 ./saved_model ./web_model
```

The conversion works fine as expected and no errors are thrown.

The problem happens when I try to use the mode using tensorflowjs:

```js
    const model = await loadGraphModel("http://127.0.0.1:8080/model.json");
    // random image so I can test
    model.executeAsync(tf.zeros([1,320,320,3]).toInt()).then(predictions => {
      console.log(predictions)
      tf.engine().endScope();
    });
```

At this moment an exception is thrown:

```
util_base.js:107 Uncaught (in promise) Error: TensorList shape mismatch:  Shapes -1 and 3 must match
    at Module.assert (util_base.js:107)
    at assertShapesMatchAllowUndefinedSize (tensor_utils.js:26)
    at TensorList.setItem (tensor_list.js:239)
    at _callee2$ (control_executor.js:309)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:282)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:116)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:32
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Module.<anonymous> (asyncToGenerator.js:21)
    at Module.executeOp (control_executor.js:411)
    at operation_executor.js:59
    at executeOp (operation_executor.js:139)
    at _loop (graph_executor.js:543)
    at GraphExecutor.processStack (graph_executor.js:579)
    at GraphExecutor._callee4$ (graph_executor.js:469)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:282)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:116)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:32
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at GraphExecutor.<anonymous> (asyncToGenerator.js:21)
    at GraphExecutor.executeWithControlFlow (graph_executor.js:513)
    at GraphExecutor._callee2$ (graph_executor.js:326)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:282)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:116)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:32
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at GraphExecutor.<anonymous> (asyncToGenerator.js:21)
    at GraphExecutor._executeAsync (graph_executor.js:365)
    at GraphExecutor._callee3$ (graph_executor.js:385)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:282)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js:116)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:32
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at GraphExecutor.<anonymous> (asyncToGenerator.js:21)
    at GraphExecutor.executeFunctionAsync (graph_executor.js:396)
    at _loop$ (control_executor.js:99)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:282)
```

I have tried using both tensorflowjs ^2.0.0 and tensorflowjs ^3.0.0 with the same error. I have trained two different models ***SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 320x320*** and ***SSD MobileNet v2 320x320*** and it is happening with both models.

I have also tried converting the model with both tensorflowjs 2 and 3 to no avail.

Comment: Could you try `model.predict(tf.zeros([1,320,320,3]), config: { batchSize: 1})`?

Comment: @yudhiesh 
`graph_executor.js:88 Uncaught (in promise) Error: This execution contains the node 'StatefulPartitionedCall/Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/ClipToWindow/Where', which has the dynamic op 'Where'. Please use model.executeAsync() instead. Alternatively, to avoid the dynamic ops, specify the inputs [StatefulPartitionedCall/Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/ClipToWindow/Reshape]`

Comment: Could you please share your model.json ?

Comment: @edkeveked https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mOdiIyd2MmXnjje1BivtpmiiKdiB56Cd/view?usp=sharing